# Open localhost on startup with Wamp

Tags: windows, wampserver

I'm new to WAMP, migrating from Server2Go, I would want to retrieve some functionalities found in S2G

I have put the WAMP shortcut in Startup directory in Windows to start WAMP on Windows startup.

Just like S2G, I would like to open chrome at localhost right after WAMP startup.

Can anybody help me on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed WAMPServer3 then there is an option to request the browser be opened when WAMPServer starts

```
right click Wampmanager-> wampmanager Settings ->Wampserver homepage at startup
```

Comment: I add WAMP 2.5.  I deinstall it and install 3.0 and found this feature thanks